# Excel VBA "On Error" trapping some but not all errors

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of embedded charts in a workbook. Some of the charts have a rectangle called "rectangle 1" and I want to modify those rectangles. The following code is supposed to do that. It works ok for some charts (both those with and without a rectangle) but then falls over on the "Set rect" line with "run time error -2147024809 (80070057) The item with the specified name wasn't found".

Any idea why the error handler isn't picking this up?

```
Sub RepositionExtrapolationRectangles()
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rect As Shape
Dim axs As Axis

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
  For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects

    With cht.Chart
      On Error GoTo skip
      Set rect = .Shapes("Rectangle 1")
      On Error GoTo 0

      Set axs = .Axes(xlCategory)
      rect.Left = .PlotArea.InsideLeft + ([CurrentDate] - axs.MinimumScale) / (axs.MaximumScale - axs.MinimumScale) * .PlotArea.InsideWidth
      rect.Width = .PlotArea.InsideLeft + .PlotArea.InsideWidth - rect.Left
      rect.Top = .PlotArea.InsideTop
      rect.Height = .PlotArea.InsideHeight
    End With
skip:


 Err.Clear

  Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some quick testing, and I can't confirm *why* the following works, but it does:

Use `On Error GoTo -1` instead of `Err.Clear`, to clear your Error Handling Object.

It seems that just using `Err.Clear` is not resetting it properly, so it cannot trap the error the second time it occurs.

At first, I thought that this might be because of the `For Each` loop, but rewriting the test code *without* a loop did not work, nor did rewriting it to not use `with` either.

Comment: Thank you @Chronocidal. That worked perfectly - even if I don't completely understand why!